# Getting document from CouchDB with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, couchdb, phantomjs

I'm writing a function to read a document out of CouchDB with PhantomJS:

```
function getDocument(dbName, id) {
  var dbPage = webpage.create();

  dbPage.open('http://127.0.0.1:5984/' + dbName + '/' + id, function (status) {
        console.log("GOT REPLY FROM SERVER:");
        console.log(dbPage.content);

        var foo = JSON.parse(dbPage.content);
        //Do something with foo...
      }
  });  
}
```

The content returned from CouchDB (dbPage.content) looks like this:
`GOT REPLY FROM SERVER:
<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"_id":"1","_rev":"1-3d3190e791500c179bdd02716add5280","myData": "d"]}
</pre></body></html>`

What is the best way for me to strip off the html, so that I can run JSON.parse to get a javascript object representing the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`page.plainText`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/plain-text.html) instead of [`page.content`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/content.html) for non-html content.